# How To enable disable view tool bar button

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created view with some tool bar button created using command framework as below

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="toolbar:com.ui.view.myview">
    <command
      commandId="com.ui.view.myview.command.Action1"
      icon=""
      label="Action1"
    </command>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command  id="com.ui.view.myview.command.Action1" name="Action1">
  </command> 
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler class="com.ui.view.myview.commands.Action1Handler" commandId="com.ui.view.myview.command.Action1">
  </handler>
</extension>
```

My viewPart contain CheckboxTableViewer 
On record selection using checkbox I want to enable the tool bar button else want to disable it.

How can i achieve this in checkbox state change listener.

```
checkboxTableViewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
                // Tool bar button enable disable logic
            }
});
```

Comment: You probably need to use `IElementUpdater` - see something like [this](http://www.robertwloch.net/2011/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-label-updating-command-handler/)

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 i got the solution from given link.